# Android: whenever a edittext field is left empty, program closes giving exception

Tags: java, android

program sudenly close when any edittext is left empty when ever i pressed a button to move to next to activity. here is the code.

```
package cme.ws.com.ws.cme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
* Created by Waqas Aamer on 5/27/2015.
*/
public class areaActivity extends Activity {

int plotarea, coveredarea;
int brickprice, blockprice, cementprice, sandprice, crushprice, ironprice;
int brickprice1, blockprice1, cementprice1, sandprice1, crushprice1, ironprice1;
int plotarea1, coveredarea1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_area);

    {
        final Context context = getApplicationContext();
        final int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

        Button movenextarea=(Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonnextexteriorwall);
        movenextarea.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                if (null != intent)
                {
                    // test = intent.getStringExtra("NameOfVariable");
                    brickprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything00", brickprice);
                    blockprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything11", blockprice);
                    sandprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything22", sandprice);
                    ironprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything33", ironprice);
                    cementprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything44", cementprice);
                    crushprice1 = intent.getIntExtra("anything55", crushprice);
                }
                EditText areanumber1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextplotarea);
                if(areanumber1 == null)
                {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill the plot area field ", duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    plotarea1 = Integer.parseInt(areanumber1.getText().toString());
                }

                EditText areanumber2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextcoveredarea);
                if(areanumber2 == null)
                {
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(context, "Please fill the covered area field ", duration);
                    toast1.show();
                }
                else
                {
                    coveredarea1 = Integer.parseInt(areanumber2.getText().toString());
                }


                int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(plotarea1);
                int oneside = sqrt;

                Intent secondActivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), exteriorwallActivity.class);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything000", brickprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything111", blockprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything222", cementprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything333", sandprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything444", ironprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything555", crushprice1);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything", oneside);
                secondActivity.putExtra("anything1", coveredarea1);
                startActivity(secondActivity);
            }

        });




    }
}
```

}

i want this that whenver a edittext box is left empty .the variable in whcih it is storing that value automatically stores 0.
eroor log is

```
07-05 23:20:42.206  14348-14348/cme.ws.com.ws.cme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
            at cme.ws.com.ws.cme.areaActivity$1.onClick(areaActivity.java:52)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did not understand..can you elaborate

Comment: If you have a crash, you should copy the exception stack trace from logcat and post it here so we can see what it says.

Comment: 07-05 23:20:42.206  14348-14348/cme.ws.com.ws.cme E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '' as integer
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:412)
            at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:382)
            at cme.ws.com.ws.cme.areaActivity$1.onClick(areaActivity.java:52)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)

Answer (score 1):

Your `EditText` fields cannot be equals `null` because in previous line of your verification you have initialized them. Instead of using `if (areanumber1 == null)` and `if (areanumber2 == null)`, check your `EditText` like this:

```
boolean isEmpty(EditText textField) {
    return textField.getText().toString().trim().length() == 0;
}
```

If function return `false` means that `EditText` is not empty and return `true` means that `EditText` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This test...

```
if(areanumber1 == null)
```

does not check if the `EditText` called `areanumber1` has no text. This checks if the variable named `areanumber1` is a null reference. Hopefully it's not since you know what IDs your layout XML is using. What's happening is your code is trying to use `parseInt()` on an empty string.

You should instead do something like this:

```
String area1text = areanumber1.getText().toString(); // works even if empty
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(area1Text)) { // text is empty
    plotarea1 = 0;
} else {
    plotarea1 = Integer.parseInt(area1text);
}
```

`TextUtils` is an Android class with some useful static methods like the one I used above. Also, make sure your `EditTexts` are using the proper `android:inputType` to restrict the text to numbers only, or else the `parseInt()` will throw an exception.

Comment: input type is integer sir

Comment: The stack trace you posted is exactly the error I described, ` unable to parse '' as integer`. You have two places where you made this mistake, did you fix both of them?